# Proving difference between two functions is small when $x$ is small...

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, monotone-functions

I'm really struggling to prove the following claim and I was wondering whether anyone could help me.

> **Claim:**$$ 0<|x| \leq 10^{-4} \implies \bigg{|} \frac{x}{e^x-1} - \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}} \bigg{|} \leq 10^{-12}$$

My attempt at a proof: I have already proven the following inequality,
$$\bigg{|} \frac{e^x-1}{x} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!} \bigg{|}  \leq \frac{|x|^ne^{|x|}}{(n+1)!}$$
So let $n=3$, then
\begin{align*}
\bigg{|} \frac{x}{e^x-1} - \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}} \bigg{|} &= \bigg{|} \frac{x}{(e^x-1)(\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!})}  \cdot \left( \frac{e^x-1}{x} - \sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}  \right) \bigg{|} \\
&= \bigg{|} \frac{x}{(e^x-1)(\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!})} \bigg{|} \cdot \bigg{|} \frac{e^x-1}{x} - \sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}  \bigg{|} \\
&\leq \bigg{|} \frac{x}{(e^x-1)(\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!})} \bigg{|} \cdot \frac{|x|^3e^{|x|}}{(3+1)!} \\
&\leq \bigg{|} \frac{x}{(e^x-1)(\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!})} \bigg{|} \cdot \frac{(10^{-4})^3 e^{10^{-4}}}{4!} \\
&= 10^{-12} \cdot \bigg{|} \frac{x}{(e^x-1)(\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!})} \bigg{|} \cdot \frac{ e^{10^{-4}}}{4!} 
\end{align*} Hence, it suffices to show that for $0 < |x| \leq 10^{-4}$, 
\begin{align*}
f(x) := \bigg{|} \frac{x}{(e^x-1)(\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!})} \bigg{|} < \frac{4!}{e^{10^{-4}}}
\end{align*}
Since $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing on the intervals $[-10^{-4}, 0)$ and $(0, 10^{-4}]$, we know that for $0 <|x| \leq 10^{-4}$, 
\begin{align*}
f(x) \leq f \left( -10^{-4} \right) \approx  1.0001 < \frac{4!}{e^{10^{-4}}}
\end{align*} Therefore, for $0 < |x| \leq 10^{-4}$,
\begin{align*}
\bigg{|} \frac{x}{e^x-1} - \frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}} \bigg{|} \leq 10^{-12} 
\end{align*} $\square$

My big problem here is that I don't actually know how to prove my claim that $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing. Does anyone know how to prove this?

Or even better, does anyone know of a more direct proof that avoids this problem altogether?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For $|x|<\epsilon=10^{-4}$, by the mean value theorem $$\left|\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right|=e^y\ge e^{-\epsilon}\ge1-\epsilon,$$ and $$1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}\ge1-\frac{\epsilon}{2},$$ so it follows that $$\left|\frac{x}{e^x-1}\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}}\right|\le\frac{1}{(1-\epsilon)^2}\le2\le\frac{4!}{e^\epsilon}$$

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me! This argument is fine for $x \geq 0$, but I don't think any similar argument works for $x < 0$...

Comment: I thought $0<x$. I'll modify for $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $|\frac{x}{e^x-1} - \frac{x}{\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^k}{k!}}| 
 = |x||\frac{\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^k}{k!} - (e^x-1)}{(e^x-1)\sum_{k=1}^3 \frac{x^k}{k!}}| $

You can use the $|x|<10^-4$ bound given, and also instead an easier inequality for the numerator using the series sum for $e^x$. Then it is clear that the denominator is obviously increasing in $x$.

So I guess this comes under "direct proof". I think your function $f(x)$ is probably decreasing though.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm not quite sure how the denominator is obviously increasing in $x$ nor how this fact if true would help establish an upper bound? Wouldn't we want the denominator to be decreasing in $x$? And I'm not sure exactly what the easier inequality for the numerator you're talking about would be?

Comment: The numerator is equal to the sum: 
$\sum_{k=4}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ which you could bound. This is using the power series expansion for $e^x$.

Denominator is increasing, that's to say that the expression as a whole is decreasing.